# Sending email to incorrect email address - are they preserved or discarded?

Tags: email

I've sent an email with some data to a wrong email address.
The domain exist, but the username (username@domain.com) doesn't.
Due to that I've got an auto reply with 550 error.
What the typical case in that situation? Is the email discarded or it stays at the recipient server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you got the bounce back, the recipient server discarded the email. You'll need to resend this email to the right email address.